# Is it possible to obtain the source code of dbms_random.random?

Tags: oracle, rdbms

Is it possible to obtain the source code of dbms_random.random? Or at least to know how it's done?

for example, one way to do is

```
  randomValue = RandSeed * $08088405 + 1
  RandSeed = randomValue
```

but how dbms_random.value did?

Answer (score 2):

Yes; search for `dbmsrand.sql`. On my Oracle 11g XE, it is located in

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\dbmsrand.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

The plsql source is available in an Oracle Database.

Read the package specs -

```
------------
    --  OVERVIEW
    --
    --  This package should be installed as SYS.  It generates a sequence of
    --  random 38-digit Oracle numbers.  The expected length of the sequence
    --  is about power(10,28), which is hopefully long enough.
    --
    --------
    --  USAGE
    --
    --  This is a random number generator.  Do not use for cryptography.
    --  For more options the cryptographic toolkit should be used.
    --
    --  By default, the package is initialized with the current user
    --  name, current time down to the second, and the current session.
    --
    --  If this package is seeded twice with the same seed, then accessed
    --  in the same way, it will produce the same results in both cases.
    --
    --------
```

[image]